# Scala matching List of tuples with guards

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, pattern-guards

I new to Scala. As an exercise I am trying to write a match statement over a list of tuples with guards. I am aware that a map would solve the problem but I am trying to gain understanding into pattern matching.

I seek to write a function that takes a `List[(Char, Int)]` as argument. The function sorts the entries and if two entries have the same key value they are added together. So the following argument `List(('q', 1'), ('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('a', 2), ('c', 1))` would become `List(('a', 3), ('c', 3'), ('q', 1))`.

I come with the following code:

```
def sortAndAggregateList(chars: List[(Char, Int)]) : List[(Char, Int)] = {
  chars match {
    case (charP1, numP1) :: (charP2, numP2) :: (x : List[(String, Int)]) if (charP1 > charP2) =>
      sortAndAggregateList((charP2, numP2) :: (charP1, numP1) :: x)
    case (charP1, numP1) :: (charP2, numP2) :: (x : List[(String, Int)]) if (charP1 < charP2) =>
      sortAndAggregateList((charP1, numP1) :: (charP2, numP2) :: x)
    case (charP1, numP1) :: (charP2, numP2) :: (x : List[(String, Int)]) if (charP1 == charP2) =>
      sortAndAggregateList((charP1, numP1 + numP2) :: x)
    case Nil =>
      Nil
  }
}
```

But I get the following warning:

:14: warning: fruitless type test: a value of type List[(Char, Int)] cannot also be a List[(String, Int)] (the underlying of List[(String, Int)]) (but still might match its erasure)

I tried dropping the List but if I do that I get an error that `x` is of type `Any`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See the error message: you are matching against `chars` which is a `List[(Char,Int)]` but in the pattern you expect `x` to be a `List[(String, Int)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is your type check which you do after each case statement (: List[(String, Int)]).

If you change your code to the following the error disappears:

```
def sortAndAggregateList(chars: List[(Char, Int)]) : List[(Char, Int)] = {
  chars match {
    case (charP1, numP1) :: (charP2, numP2) :: x if (charP1 > charP2) =>
      sortList(p1 :: p2 :: x)
    case (charP1, numP1) :: (charP2, numP2) :: x if (charP1 < charP2) =>
      sortList(p2 :: p1 :: x)
    case (charP1, numP1) :: (charP2, numP2) :: x if (charP1 == charP2) =>
        val p3: (Char, Int) = (charP1, numP1 + numP2)
        sortList(p3 :: x)
    case x =>
      x
    case Nil =>
      Nil
  }
}
```

Afterwards you'll find out that the compiler tells you that p1 and p2 are undefined. To fix this you need to set them as p1 = (charP1, numP1) and p2 = (charP2, numP2).
To solve this with your syntax you can do the following:

```
def sortAndAggregateList(chars: List[(Char, Int)]) : List[(Char, Int)] = {
  chars match {
    case (charP1, numP1) :: (charP2, numP2) :: x if (charP1 > charP2) =>
      sortList((charP1, numP1) :: (charP2, numP2) :: x)
    case (charP1, numP1) :: (charP2, numP2) :: x if (charP1 < charP2) =>
      sortList((charP2, numP2) :: (charP1, numP1) :: x)
    case (charP1, numP1) :: (charP2, numP2) :: x if (charP1 == charP2) =>
        val p3: (Char, Int) = (charP1, numP1 + numP2)
        sortList(p3 :: x)
    case x =>
      x
    case Nil =>
      Nil
  }
}
```

Now the only missing link is the sortList function which you've not added.
I'm not sure if this will work because I think the case:

```
case x => x
```

should be:

```
case x :: Nil => x :: Nil
```

Otherwise x would match anything. Which also leaves you the possibility to remove the case:

```
case Nil => Nil
```

if you don't want to remove case x => x

Comment: yes you're right, that's why I added that it matches anything, even Nil.

Comment: case Nil => Nil is redundant

Answer (score 0):

Extra type annotation after x is not necessary and wrong.

remove this

```
(x : List[(String, Int)])
```

instead use (not compulsory. you can omit the type annotation)

```
(x : List[(Char, Int)])
```

Complete function

```
  def sortAndAggregateList(chars: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] = chars match {
    case (charP1, numP1) :: (charP2, numP2) :: x if charP1 > charP2 =>

      sortAndAggregateList((charP2, numP2) :: (charP1, numP1) :: x)

    case (charP1, numP1) :: (charP2, numP2) :: x if charP1 < charP2 =>

      sortAndAggregateList((charP1, numP1) :: (charP2, numP2) :: x)

    case (charP1, numP1) :: (charP2, numP2) :: x if charP1 == charP2 =>

      sortAndAggregateList((charP1, numP1 + numP2) :: x)

    case x => x
  }
```

The code will be much more cleaner if you consider collapsing the tuples

```
  def sortAndAggregateList(chars: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] = chars match {
    case a :: b :: x if a._1 > b._2 =>

      sortAndAggregateList(b :: a :: x)

    case a :: b :: x if a._1 < b._1 =>

      sortAndAggregateList(a :: b :: x)

    case a :: b :: x if a._1 == b._1 =>

      sortAndAggregateList((a._1, (a._2 + b._2)) :: x)

   case x => x

  }
```

case `case x => x` will match both list Nil case and list having one element case.

Comment: This function has one weakness. It won't work with a list containing only one entry like: List(("t", 1))